# Spawn within field of view but always below a certain height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two systems that spawn flying enemies. The first system spawns enemies within the FOV:

```
distanceFromPlayer = 20;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)leftRange,(float)rightRange), UnityEngine.Random.Range((float)bottomRange,(float)topRange), 0));
screenPosition = ray.GetPoint (distanceFromPlayer);
```

The second system spawns them randomly but with a max angle between enemy and ground. Look at it as if there was a half sphere with the player as center that has been topped off: the enemy can spawn on the surface of that topped sphere:

```
float distance = distanceFromPlayer;
float yaw = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,360);
float pitch = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,35);
screenPosition = RotationHelper.ConvertYawPitch (Vector3.forward * distance, yaw, pitch);
```

and

```
public static class RotationHelper {

    public static Vector3 ConvertYawPitch(Vector3 vector, float yaw, float pitch)
    {
        Quaternion yawRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (yaw, Vector3.up);
        Vector3 yawedZAxis = yawRotation * Vector3.left;
        Quaternion pitchRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis (pitch, yawedZAxis);
        Vector3 yawedVector = yawRotation * vector;
        Vector3 position = pitchRotation * yawedVector;
        return position;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to have a third system for another type of enemies, which basically combines the two systems. So: I want them to spawn inside the field of view, but not above a certain hight, measured from the ground (or below a certain angle like in system two). So if you look to the sky, it should spawn the enemies below the camera's field of view.

I've tried an approach where I make a dummy camera that moves along with the real camera, but can't look upside, but I have the feeling it affects my performance quite drastically, and it doesn't feel like the most efficient way to do it.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is it not possible that you spawn them and then move them downwards based on your constraints?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The enemies hover on the spot, they don't move towards new positions.

Comment: So then from your calculated **screenPosition** you could get the directional vector towards the ground and just move that point down/up. Before spawning them

Comment: That's a good idea. However, I want all my enemies to be at the exact same distance from the camera (i.e. the player). When I move them down, the distance will be slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for an approach where I put an invisible ceiling above the player that follows the player's position. If an enemy would spawn behind this invisible ceiling, I recalculate the spawn point.

I use the same technique to make sure enemies don't spawn beneath the floor or behind objects.

This is probably not the most performance friendly way because chances are quite high that it needs to recalculate, so feel free to share other approaches.